# python 3 How do I send multidimentional array data to a subprocess.call()

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a shell command I need to send a multidimensional array as parameters.

```
subprocess.call(['rndc', 'addzone', domain, 'in', 'external', '"{type master; auto-dnssec maintain; inline-signing yes; key-directory \"/home/ex-mailer-domains/domain.com/\"; file \"/home/ex-mailer-domains/domain.com/domain.com.external\"; update-policy { grant ddns-key zonesub ANY; };};"'

subprocess.call(['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
```

the error I am receiving:

```
[\u@yoda:/usr/local/etc/namedb] # python3.4 makedomain3.py mylabel domain.com 108.61.169.203 255.255.254.0 2001:19f0:5800:8561:5400:00ff:fe07:cae5 1
  File "makecustdomain3.py", line 249
    subprocess.call(['rndc', 'loadkeys', domain])
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

actual command in the shell:

```
rndc addzone domain.com in external '{type master; auto-dnssec maintain; inline-signing yes; key-directory "/home/ex-mailer-domains/domain.com/"; file "/home/ex-mailer-domains/nyctelecomm2.com/domain.com.external"; update-policy { grant ddns-key zonesub ANY; };};'
rndc loadkeys domain.com
```

How do you correctly pass multidimensional array data as a parameter to a subprocess.call() in python3?

Comment: "multi-dimensional array" is irrelevant here. From your example, it's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you failed to close off the previous call.  The first call in your posting ends with **"'**; these close off the structure string, but you still need a right bracket and right parenthesis.

The parser detects this at the end of the following token; syntactically, it should have seen either the right bracket or another comma.

Comment: Welcome to the club; most of us are long-time members.  This is one of the first things I've taught my students: when the error appears at the start of a line, also look at the end of the previous line.